# Plugin.Maui.Audio not playing Local Files

Tags: maui, mp3

I have already asked this question, but I think this simplified version better explains the problem,

In a .net 7.0  maui app, using Plugin.Maui.Audio, I am using the following code to try and play a local mp3 file (That has been downloaded)

```
filePath = "/data/user/0/com.companyname.myapp/files/1.mp3";
var player = AudioManager.Current.CreatePlayer(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filePath));
player.Play();
```

It returns:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: '/data/user/0/com.companyname.myapp/files/1.mp3'
```

When build in Visual Studio 2022 and run on Android Emulator, or Physical Samsung Android Device.

The file definetly exists, as :
`File.Exists(sermon.FileUri)`
returns true

I have also tried with:

```
filePath = "file///data/user/0/com.companyname.sermonsearch/files/1.mp3";
var player = AudioManager.Current.CreatePlayer(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filePath));
player.Play();
```

Same error. File Not found.

Also if I copy the file 1.mp3 using adb shell to my local pc, it plays correctly as an mp3, so file is good!.

Comment: `OpenAppPackageFileAsync` is for files that are bundled within the app package, not files that are created at runtime

Comment: Hi Jason, I tried:    filePath = "file///data/user/0/com.companyname.myapp/files/1.mp3";
  var player = AudioManager.Current.CreatePlayer(filePath);
  player.Play();  Same result.

Comment: that's a URI, not a path.  `CreatePlayer` accepts either a path or a stream